# DefaultHandler characters() method behavior

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I have just read that `characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)` can get called multiple times for one inner XML data (e.g. `<name>John Smith</name>`).

In my project I have to parse big XML file (1.5 GB) and put it in the database, so I cant just manually go through the database and the file to see if everything is OK. So my question is is it safe to do something like this:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
      dataForDatabase = new String(ch,start,length);
}
```

Where `dataForDatabase` is this parser's class member.

and after that in endElement...

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qname) throws SAXException {
     putDataToDatabase(dataForDatabase);
}
```

Won't `dataForDatabase` get overridden if `characters()` method gets called multiple times?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be overwritten. You should use a stringbuilder and append the characters. Initialize the stringbuilder in the startElement. In the endElement you can indeed store it to the database.